# The application on react + redux + react-dnd does not work after assembly, why?

Tags: react-redux

when running the test script an error occurs

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect (DragD
ropContext (App)) ". Either wrap the root component in a,
or pass a custom React context provider to and the
corresponding React context Consumer Connect (DragDropContext (App)) in connect options.

although everything works in an unassembled project. As I understand it, there are some problems due to the fact that the root component is wrapped in two hocs - one redox, the other dnd.

```
ReactDOM.render(<DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <App />
                    </Provider>
                </DragDropContextProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried to wrap first in dnd, then in redaks - it did not help, everything is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mixed up the legacy decorator API with the top-level API

#### Legacy Decorator API

With legacy decorator you can wrap as following:

```
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd'

class YourApp {
  /* ... */
}

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App)
```

Check the documentation about Legacy Decorator API [here...](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-drop-context)

#### Top-Level API

For the Top-Level API you use:

```
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
....
...
        <div className="App">
            <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <App />
            </DndProvider>
        </div>
```

Check the documentation about Top-level API [here...](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/dnd-provider)